# How to find all href in an element in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have found an element and want to find all href in this element. I tried to get all the links but only the first one was obtained.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='msg']/div[@class='']")
href = element.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href') #only get first link
```

What is the correct method to do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch all href link using selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759787/fetch-all-href-link-using-selenium-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the Selenium docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements).

> To find multiple elements (these methods will return a list)...

The multiple element version for css is `find_elements_by_css_selector`.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='msg']/div[@class='']")
hrefs = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in element.find_elements_by_css_selector('a')]
```